# What is the difference between "supersede" and "obviate"?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, differences, synonyms

This is more related to project management/software. Sometimes I got a ticket that *comes in the place of another ticket*. Which would be a better word to use: *supersede* or *obviate*?

**Supersede:** take the place of (a person or thing previously in authority or use); supplant.

**Obviate:** remove (a need or difficulty).

Comment: It's not clear whether the other ticket was already in play and the new ticket replaced it, or the ticket came instead of the other ticket. And does the new ticket countermand the old ticket, in which case supersede would be your perfect word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely use ***"supersede"***. It's much more idiomatic. *"Obviate"* is not really a proper definition for what you want and even if it were it would only serve to confuse other developers potentially.

Go with ***"supersede".***

Comment: This. *Obviate* would apply if something else happened, rendering the old ticket no longer applicable, rather than it being *superseded* by a new ticket.

Comment: @Davo I agree. Though obviate would be less desired than simple, "replaced". In a project management environment, likely a tech type job, the tickets usually are created and may have a higher priority than the previous one. So it's much more common that a ticket will supersede another but, yes, obviate could work in that case; though I would prefer "replaced" in that case.